# Passing & in query as slug mvc

Tags: slug, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I'm seem to be experiencing a small issue regarding & within a slug url.

I have a slug as follows:

www.mydomain.com.au/27/this-is-my-slug-&-some

When I click on this I get the following error

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Runtime Error 
An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed
```

I've tried wrapping

```
Server.UrlEncode(t.slug)
```

yet when I click on the link I get another error:

```
HTTP Error 404.11 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence.
```

I url's very similar to stackoverflow.

Any help would be grand.

Comment: I think you are on to a loser here with the ampersand....is it possible to use the word "and" instead?

If you want to see the full error then you need to look in the logs (assuming this is a production environment) or turn custom errors off in the web.config. If you can post the error message and call stack we can help more

Comment: I looked at StackOverflows url regarding this question and they've removed the & from the URL, so I will follow what they have done.